# Create an object from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, javascript-objects

I two have arrays

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
```

i created an object from them using `.map`

```
let labels = arr1.map(value => ({'y': value}));
let series = arr2.map(value => ({'x': value}));
```

and merged object using `_.merge` from lodash

```
let mergeData = _.merge({}, series2, labels2);
```

result looks similar to this:

```
{x: 1, y: 25},
{x: 2, y: 38},
{x: 3, y: 24},
{x: 4, y: 60},
{x: 5, y: 22}
```

Now what i would like to display is an array of objects *(in this case it will display just one object inside array)* which looks like one below:

```
graphs: [
  {
    label: 'area 1',
    values: [
      {x: 1, y: 25},
      {x: 2, y: 38},
      {x: 3, y: 24},
      {x: 4, y: 60},
      {x: 5, y: 22}
    ]
  },
]
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to loop over the `object['values']` field?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#map` and create the values object.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
    values = arr1.map((x, i) => ({x,y: arr2[i]})),
    output = { graphs: [{ label: 'area 1', values }]};
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd concat objects inside of an array as such:

```
let mergeData = [].concat(_.merge({}, series2, labels2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.zip()` to convert both arrays to an array of pairs `[[1, 6], [2, 7],...]`, then map the array of pairs, and use `_.zipObject()` to create an object with the `['x', 'y']` properties:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

const result = _.map(
  _.zip(arr1, arr2), // combine each column to a pair [1, 6],  [2, 7], etc...
  _.partial(_.zipObject, ['x', 'y']) // create a function that converts each pair to an object
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```